# Livy server not starting in Cloudera

Tags: java, linux, apache-spark, cloudera, hue

I am trying to start the livy server so that I can use the spark in the Hue notebook. I am using the cloudera Manager 5.7.

I tried the following to start the livy-server:

```
cd /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.0-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.45/lib/hue/build/env/bin
sudo ./hue livy_server
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.cloudera.hue.livy.server.Main
```

Since livy server is supposed to be pre-built in Cloudera Manager, I don't think it's the problem with building. I was thinking maybe I would have to add

```
export CLASSPATH=CLASSPATH:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.0-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.45/lib/hue/apps/spark/java/livy-server/src/main/scala/com/cloudera/hue/livy/server
```

Because this is where I have the Main.scala

But still no luck. I just started working with this so I don't have much idea about this livy server. Any ideas anyone?

Thank you !

Comment: In 5.7 Livy is not been built in Hue, you will need to build it https://github.com/cloudera/hue/tree/master/apps/spark/java#building-livy

Comment: Thanks @Romain for the comment. But could you give some reference to confirm that Livy is not built in Hue 5.7?

Comment: Have a look at @Romain's: [StackOverflow profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/73117/romain) and [commits to Hue](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/graphs/contributors). I reckon Romain's comment *is* an authoritative reference.